# Endless report loading

Tags: powerbi

I try to print a Power Bi report from the "embedUrl" var return:

```
  "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=[...]&groupId=[...]&w=2&config=[...]"
```

I put in an iframe

```
<iframe title="embedUrl"
        width="600"
        height="600"
        src="<?php echo $content->embedUrl ?>">
</iframe>
```

as in an embed, but in either case the report is loading eternaly.

[image]

without errors, but the report is never displayed.

where can the error come from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add the &autoAuth=true param to the embedUrl returning by power bi.